# Luabind: return_stl_iterator for std::map

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

Is there any way to return an STL iterator to a `std::map` (e.g. `std::map<const std::string, int>`)?

Luabind definition for an example class:

```
class_<SomeClass>( "SomeClass" )
  .property( "items", &SomeClass::GetItems, return_stl_iterator )
```

`GetItems()` returns a const reference to a `std::map` container.

When accessing it in Lua like this:

```
for item in some_class.items do
  ...
end
```

Luabind throws a std::runtime_error saying *"Trying to use unregistered class"*. Is iterating over `std::map`s not possible? (the documentation says that all containers having `begin()` and `end()` work...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After browsing the source code I discovered that the Luabind return_stl_iterator policy only supports iterators that reference the wanted datatype directly. Iterators for associative containers are not supported (`first` and `second` are never accessed).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the "unregistered class" is `std::pair<const std::string, int>`.  Can you try registering that with Luabind and see if it works then?